# problem with tilde and squaring overlined symbols, stix2

Tags: tilde, stix

I have problem with the following math text:
[image]

As you can see, the tilde over S is not actually wide, but it's squared nicely. On the other hand, the overline over the X is okay, but the deuce is placed ugly.

Im using Stix 2.0. I'd like to have tilde as wide as overline over the X and the square of X be positioned properly.

How to achieve it without changing math font?

I use XeLaTex. Stix2 is loaded as in MWE:

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[StylisticSet=02]
\begin{document}
$$\widetilde{S}^2 = \int x^2 dF_n - \left(\int x dF_n\right)^2 
     = \frac{1}{n}\sum X_i^2 - \overline{X}^2$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show the compilable code resulting in your shown screenshot.

Comment: Please tell us whether you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and how exactly you load the `Stix Two Math` font.

Comment: @Mico, i've edited the question

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: @SandyG, thx, I've edited the answer again!

Comment: You might use `\wideoverbar` instead. Don't load `xunicode`, it's not necessary any longer. On the other hand, I'd go with `\tilde` and `\bar`.

Comment: thx, @egreg! \wideoverbar works for me! Any idea how to solve tilde problem? Right now it's too small, doesnt look like tilde at all, unless i zoom in enough..

Comment: @Ilya68 Wrong shape designed by the developers of STIX fonts?

Comment: @egreg, you asking? )) im relatively new to latex.. cant know.. i saw that mtpro2 has good and customizable overlines/tildes etc.. thought that stix might have similar commands as well, though i havent found any documentation on STIX commands, only symbol set and stylistic sets. So asked here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\wideoverbar` instead of `\overline`.

For the tilde, you can substitute it with the one from TeX Gyre Termes, but some low level tricks are necessary.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[StylisticSet=02]

\newfontface{\termesmath}{texgyretermes-math.otf}[NFSSFamily=termesmath]
\DeclareSymbolFont{termesmath}{TU}{termesmath}{m}{n}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \protected\def\widetilde{\Umathaccent 7 \symtermesmath "00303\relax}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\widetilde{S}^2
= \int x^2 \,dF_n - \left(\,\int x \,dF_n\right)^{\!2}
= \frac{1}{n}\sum X_i^2 - \wideoverbar{X}^2
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem with TeX Gyre Heros, and changing a \tilde to \widetilde fixed my problem (of the tilde being too low).