# stix2, overline and superscripts

Tags: math-mode, superscripts, stix

Consider the following MWE *without* stix2 loaded (looks nice with and without overline):

[image]

And *with* stix2 loaded (looks nice without but horrible with overline):

[image]

The overline is placed a bit high, but my main issue is that the superscript is placed far too high for some reason. A very similar problem was reported and fixed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479672/64293), but it uses XeLaTeX (I'm using pdflatex) and the proposed solution using `\wideoverbar` does not appear to be available for use with pdflatex?

Is this a bug? Can I fix it somehow?

MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\tran}{^{\mkern-1.5mu\mathsf{T}}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation*}
    h \tran s \qquad h^2 s
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \overline{h}\tran \overline{s} \qquad \overline{h}^2 \overline{s}
\end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\bar` and you'll get better results. Don't worry if you think it's too short: it isn't.

Comment: @egreg I'd do so (`\bar` indeed looks fine), but unfortunately, I also have multi-letter variables (such as `\mathrm{MUAP}`) for which I need the same functionality. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the question!